# How to check each letter of a word in a spiraling fashion and returning a bool, in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For example the word 'urgent' starting at u, moving to the end - t, back to r, n, g, and finally e (starting form the outside and moving inwards). Also for this particular word it is in reverse alphabetical order  -> u to e, so it would return False.

I was thinking of doing it as a for loop using indexing so [0] for u [:-1] for t, however I do want to be able to do this for words of any length so this method does not seem to work. Is there anything like .split() which can find the first and last character and so on moving inwards?

Comment: What would you be checking each letter against? What happens if a word is of uneven length?

Comment: with whom u comapring

Comment: Interesting problem but you have to show some effort. So show us your code, that is, your attempt to make your code do what you want it to do. If we can't see it, we can't help. And please take the time to read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You might want to elaborate the rules for assigning a Boolean value. Seemingly nobody understands them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below :

```
def spiral_comp(word):
    _start=0
    _end=len(word)-1
    vowel=['a','e','i','o','u']
if len(word)%2 == 0: # for even length

    for i in range(int(len(word)/2)):
        print(word[_start], word[_end])
        if word[_start] in vowel:
            word[_start] #do stuff
        _start += 1
        if word[_end] in vowel:
            word[_end]  # do stuff
        _end-=1

else: #for odd length
    for i in range(int(len(word)/2)+1):
        if i == int(len(word)/2):
            if word[_start] in vowel:
                print(word[_start])
                #do stuff
                continue
        print(word[_start], word[_end])
        if word[_start] in vowel:
            word[_start] #do stuff
        _start += 1
        if word[_end] in vowel:
            word[_end] # do stuff
        _end-=1
```

spiral_comp('urgent')

```
Prints:
u t
r n
g e
```

spiral_comp('spoon')

```
Prints:
s n
p o
o
```